# hasOwnProperty returns empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have table to be displayed from JSON

```
<th>
    {
        x.amountForQuantity.filter((remaining) => {
            return remaining.hasOwnProperty(cost.key);
        })[cost.key]
    }
</th>
```

The above tag returns empty, What i am making wrong here ?

Sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-chandrasekhar-gg5iy?file=/src/App.js:1122-1374)

Comment: `filter` returns an array. Why are you trying to access `cost.key` index from that array? `cost.key` has strings values like `"Labour Cost"`

Comment: need to show that in a table

Comment: You need use `find` and change the condition as well: `x.amountForQuantity.find(a => a.key === cost.key)?.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array structure is like this

```
const row = [
...
      amountForQuantity: [
        {
          key: "Labour Cost",
          value: 150
        },
        {
          key: "Material Cost",
          value: 570
        }]
    ...
  ];
```

So the `cost.key` is not a property of the object but a `value` of the `key` property.

So your code should be like this.

```
x.amountForQuantity.filter((remaining) => remaining.key == cost.key)[0].value
```